# Is it bad practice to use process.env.SOMETHING in a npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Specifically, I have created a wrapper for winston, so only a few functions are available and it can always be swapped out for some other library.
In this wrapper I am creating a new logger with:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.MIN_LOG_LEVEL || 'debug', // Minimum logging level
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
  format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), customFormat),
});
```

Is it a bad practice to use *process.env.MIN_LOG_LEVEL* here? Should it only be used in the "actual app" ? And if so, how would you solve this?

Comment: This is not a technical question, it may be better suited to Stack Exchange than Stack Overflow. I think it is OK the way you use it, but it must be well documented.

Comment: Thank you! Can you make an example for what a technical question looks like?

Comment: In an case like this people ask about code that do not work, but is right according to documentation. The base of your question is not technical, your code works fine, so it cannot be reformulated.

Comment: Working code + is this bad practice to do X -> CodeReview SE. Not saying you won't get an answer here, but it's right that SO works best for "I have this code, I expect this behaviour but encounter this one" questions.

Comment: Apparently they do not agree: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191702/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-process-env-something-in-a-npm-package